# Как можно отловить создание любого поля для ввода на странице?

Tags: javascript, pure_js

Доброго времени суток!

Допустим есть огромная программа, в разных местах которой по определенной логике добавляются или удаляются `html`-элементы. Все это происходит банальной подстановкой нужного `html` в нужное место. В некоторых частях вставляемого `html` могут быть *любые* поля ввода. Вопрос в следующем:
**как можно отловить создание любого поля для ввода на странице и в любом месте, на протяжении всей работы программы, при том сделав такой обработчик только в одном месте, не затрагивая остальную логику программы?** Затем всем этим полям надо присвоить один и тот же метод при blur и focus, но это уже другой вопрос.

**PS**:
Без использования `jQuery` и любых подобных библиотек. Я не могу подключить ее в программу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[DOMNodeInserted](http://help.dottoro.com/ljmcxjla.php) event

```
document.body.addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted', function(el) {
   // выведем в консоль добавленный элемент
   console.log(el.srcElement);
})​​​​​​​​​​;
```

Comment: Да, неплохой способ, спасибо!

Comment: Советую также обратить внимание на этот [ответ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844565/is-there-a-jquery-dom-change-listener/11546242#11546242)